# C++ Linker Error involving operator overload function

Tags: c++, list, operator-overloading, linker-errors

I have a List of type Node. I want to set a temporary Node equal to the Node at the front of the List, as follows:

```
class Node
{ 
   public:
      Node();
      Node& operator = (const Node& n);
};
```

but I keep getting a Linker Error:

> Linking...
>   main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class Node & __thiscall Node::operator=(class Node const &)" (??4Node@@QAEAAV0@ABV0@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl fillScan(int,class std::list >)" (?fillScan@@YAXHV?$list@VNode@@V?$allocator@VNode@@@std@@@std@@@Z)
>   C:\Users\Aaron McKellar\Documents\School Stuff\CS445\Test\Debug\Test.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I have not done operator overloading in some time. I am still having trouble with this even after looking through my book and online.

class Node
{ 
   public:
      Node();
      int y;
      Node& operator=(const Node& n);
};
Node::Node() // Default constructor
{
  y = -1;
}

Node& Node::operator=(const Node& n) 
{
   if(this != n)
   {
      this.y =  n.y;
   }
   return *this;
}

I don't know what is wrong but when I do this.y intellisense does not recognize this as being a Node object. Please help and thanks!

Comment: 1>Compiling...
1>main.cpp
1>c:\users\aaron mckellar\documents\school stuff\cs445\test\test\main.cpp(49) : error C2679: binary '!=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const Node' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>        could be 'built-in C++ operator!=(Node *, Node *)'
1>        c:\program files\microsoft sdks\windows\v6.0a\include\guiddef.h(197): or       'int operator !=(const GUID &,const GUID &)'
1>        while trying to match the argument list '(Node *const , const Node)'

Comment: 1>c:\users\aaron mckellar\documents\school stuff\cs445\test\test\main.cpp(51) : error C2228: left of '.y' must have class/struct/union
1>        type is 'Node *const '
1>        did you intend to use '->' instead?

Comment: I also tried return this = n; 

but I got this:

1>c:\users\aaron mckellar\documents\school stuff\cs445\test\test\main.cpp(56) : error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const Node' to 'Node *const '
1>        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only showed the declaration of `operator=`, not the definition. Either you didn't supply a definition or the linker can't find it.

Well, I should say: The linker definitely can't find the definition for `operator=`. Either that's because you forgot to supply one or because your project/Makefile is set up incorrectly.

Comment: please view my comments above

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a definition for `operator=`, of course:

```
Node& Node::operator=(const Node& n) {

     // 'copy' semantics for Node
}
```

Note that the compiler generates the assignment operator by itself using memberwise copy if none is provided. Use the compiler-generated operator if sufficient.

Comment: please view my comments above